# Connecting db using shell script by passing db credentials from shell

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, shell

Hi I am trying to connect my database using shell script and by passing the db credentials from shell. I am getting "ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified". Please find the script below.

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_CREDENTIALS=$1

mkdir -p $PWD/logs

sqlplus -silent $DB_CREDENTIALS <<EOFSQL

set echo on
set timing on
set heading on
set feedback on
set linesize 5000
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TRIMSPOOL ON


@teshscrpt.sql


EOFSQL
```

And the error is :

```
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [logon] [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER}]
where <logon>  ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>] | /
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
```

Can somebody help me out kindly.

Thanks,
sudhir.

Comment: And how do you call your script ?

Comment: I am trying to call my script from shell  like "bash-4.2$ dbcheck.sh"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should take the habit of quoting your variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_CREDENTIALS="$1"                         # HERE

mkdir -p "$PWD"/logs                        # HERE

sqlplus -silent "$DB_CREDENTIALS" <<EOFSQL  # HERE
```

Then:

> I am trying to call my script from shell like `bash-4.2$ dbcheck.sh`

Obviously, your script take the connection parameters as first argument. you should invoke it like that:

```
bash-4.2$ dbcheck.sh username/password@my.oracle.host
```

Comment: Thanks alot Sylvalin Leroux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put correct credentials. Launch it like this:

`dbcheck.sh username/password@database`

Have you read the correct sqlplus syntax?